# Type casting int into double C++

Tags: c++, windows, casting

I am new to programming and this might be an obvious question, though i cannot for life of me figure out why my program is not returning as a double.

I am suppose to write a stocks program that takes in shares of stock, whole dollar portion of price and the fraction portion. And the fraction portion is to be inputted as two int values, and include a function definition with 3 int values.The function returns the price as a double.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int price(int, int, int);

int main()
{
    int dollars, numerator, denominator, price1, shares;
    char ans;
    do
    {
        cout<<"Enter the stock price and the number of shares.\n";
        cout<<"Enter the price and integers: Dollars, numerator, denominator\n";
        cin>>dollars>>numerator>>denominator;
        cout<<"Enter the number of shares held\n";
        cin>>shares;
        cout<<shares;
        price1 = price(dollars,numerator,denominator);
        cout<<" shares of stock with market price of ";
        cout<< dollars << " " << numerator<<'/'<<denominator<<endl;
        cout<<"have a value of " << shares * price1<<endl;
        cout<<"Enter either Y/y to continue";
        cin>>ans;
    }while (ans == 'Y' || ans == 'y');
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int price(int dollars, int numerator, int denominator)
{
    return dollars + numerator/static_cast<double>(denominator);
}
```

Comment: "The function returns the price as a double." Hm, no; you have `int` as the return type, after all.

Comment: Gack. Nobody does stock prices with fractions any more. It's all decimal.

Answer (score 3):

That's because your variables are of type int. Hence you are losing precision.

Change your int return types and variables to doubles.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
double price(double, double, double);
int main()
{
  double dollars, numerator, denominator, price1, shares;
char ans;
do
{
cout<<"Enter the stock price and the number of shares.\n";
cout<<"Enter the price and integers: Dollars, numerator, denominator\n";
cin>>dollars>>numerator>>denominator;
cout<<"Enter the number of shares held\n";
cin>>shares;
cout<<shares;
price1 = price(dollars,numerator,denominator);
cout<<" shares of stock with market price of ";
cout<< dollars << " " << numerator<<'/'<<denominator<<endl;
cout<<"have a value of " << shares * price1<<endl;
cout<<"Enter either Y/y to continue";
cin>>ans;
}while (ans == 'Y' || ans == 'y');
system("pause");
return 0;
}
double price(double dollars, double numerator, double denominator)
{
  return dollars + numerator/denominator;
}
```

Comment: i could just put all of them as doubles, but my assignments states that the user should be entering 3 int values, and include 3 int arguments in the function definition. Reading this i assumed I would have to stac_cast and int to a double, though it does not seem to be working. I have tried Wallyk's suggestion of putting (Double) in fron of Num/Denom though it did not turn my answer into a double

Comment: What you can do is return a double then.The function definition doesn't seem to specify what the return type is. So use a double not int. 
Try static_cast or cast to a double, but what the function returns *must* be a double. Your assignment has some strange requirements :(

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are returning an `int`.  This will fix it.

```
double price (int dollars, int numerator, int denominator)
{ 
    return dollars + (double) numerator / denominator;
}
```